# Unity: finding force vector to separate colliders in OnTriggerStay events

Tags: unity, vector, collider

In Unity, I have Trigger Colliders, and catch the OnTriggerStay(Collider other) events.

Once two Colliders are touching, how do I get the Force vector to make them want to separate again?

In the example below, I have a Sphere and a Box Collider touching. The OnTriggerStay is being called for the Sphere.

[image]

I cannot use the center positions of the transforms to get a direction, as that would not give me a very good force vector:

[image]

And I do not think I can use the Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds to figure out the Box touch position, because the point I look from (center of Sphere), could be inside the Box Collider itself, which I understand will just return me back the center of the Sphere again. I would not be able to resolve any force vector from that.

[image]

Comment: Are your colliders always in box-sphere pairs, or do you need to handle other pairs?

Comment: Well, box-sphere pairs would be a good start if there is no general way of solving this. =)